# C++ - shared library liblog4cpp.so.4 not found

Tags: c++, linux, lib

I tried to run a program that requires log4cpp, 
I got following error when I try to  run the program

> error while loading shared libraries: liblog4cpp.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have set the library path in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and these are the files in my `/usr/local/lib` directory:

```
liblog4cpp.a    
liblog4cpp.so     
liblog4cpp.so.5.0.6 
liblog4cpp.la  
liblog4cpp.so.5   
pkgconfig
```

What could be the problem here ?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrrooooongggg verssssiiiooooonnn

Comment: Re-read the error message and then compare it to the list of files you posted. You'll spot it.

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so` shows?

Comment: yes! I noticed that but does it requires the exact same version ? I mean I have a newer version than the program asking for. (sorry I'm still a noob on this)

Comment: @dlmeetei,
lots of unreadable things like ▒▒▒▒
L▒▒▒▒"
f▒&S▒"
▒▒%▒▒!▒o((▒▒"
▒▒N▒"
&▒▒▒▒"

Comment: @Sameera.San, something wrong, I just wanted to check if the so is symbolic link to `liblog4cpp.so.4`. But it seems to be corrupted on ur system.

Comment: yah seems like this system has an issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Use 
 ldd [program name] 
so see what's actually loaded (assuming you are on a Unix system since you use LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

Comment: 'not a dynamic executable'
and I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not a dynamic executable' ? should the library be statically linked ? RHEL does have ldd. Try it an post the output.

Comment: The output is:  not a dynamic executable

Comment: Did you use ldd on your program or on the library ? you should use it on the same executable that you use to start the program.

Comment: ah, probably wrong library. Check for 32/64 bit libraries.

Comment: Yes I used it on my program, like # ldd program.sh and that's all I got as an output

Comment: install the following to make ldd work : sudo yum install glibc.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++.i686 glibc-devel.i686